# how to calculate the coefficient of a multivariable polynomial

Tags: combinatorics

What is  the coefficient $c$ of the term $x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2\cdots x_{12}^2$  in the expansion of  the following multivariable polynomial:

$(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)(x_1-x_{10})(x_2-x_3)(x_2-x_5)(x_2-x_{11})(x_3-x_6)(x_3-x_{12})(x_4-x_5)(x_4-x_6)(x_4-x_7)(x_5-x_6)(x_5-x_8)(x_6-x_9)(x_7-x_8)(x_7-x_9)(x_7-x_{10})(x_8-x_9)(x_8-x_{11})(x_9-x_{12})(x_{10}-x_{11})(x_{10}-x_{12})(x_{11}-x_{12})$

I wish to know the theoretical methods to find the coefficient $c$,  although I know the coefficient $c=-36$  which can be obtained by Mathematica or Maple .  I hope the answers. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a pattern to the entries in the products?

Comment: @Burr  If we recognized each $x_i$ as a vertex and each factor as a edge, the we get a grid graph on the  torus.

Comment: Note that if you choose one element of each factor and get the desired term, then choosing the opposite element of each factor also gets the desired term (with the same sign).

Comment: So, this counts a signed number of directed graphs for which every vertex has in-degree $2$.

Comment: @Burr what is a signed number of a  directed graph? Does this method  induce an effective calculation for the coefficient c?